# Evaluation of $\int_{0}^{10 \pi} ([\sec ^{-1}x]+[\cot^{-1} x])~\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Find the value of the integral

$$\int_{0}^{10 \pi} (\lfloor\sec ^{-1}x\rfloor+\lfloor\cot^{-1} x\rfloor)~\mathrm dx$$

where $\lfloor . \rfloor$ denotes greatest integer function.

Could some help me with this? I cannot break greatest integer function here into different interval. Please provide some insight.

Comment: @Mathematics Yeah I agree- I had just given the problem a cursory look and thought I'd throw them out there.

Comment: Don't forget the $\mathrm dx$. This is very important, especially if you like to get the right answer!

Answer (score 4):

$\left\lfloor \sec^{-1}x\right\rfloor=\begin{cases}
                                       0 & \text{ for } x<\sec(1)\approx1.851\\
                                       1 & \text{ for } x\ge\sec(1)
                                       \end{cases}$

$\left\lfloor\cot^{-1}x\right\rfloor=\begin{cases}
                                       1 & \text{ for } 0\le x<\cot(1)\approx0.642\\
                                       0 & \text{ for } x\ge\cot(1)
                                       \end{cases}$

So
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^{10\pi}\left\lfloor \sec^{-1}x\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\cot^{-1}x\right\rfloor\,dx
&=\int_0^{\cot(1)}1+0\,dx+\int_{\sec(1)}^{10\pi}0+1\,dx\\
&=\cot(1)+10\pi-\sec(1)
\end{eqnarray}

[Graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5wcfrwhkie)

Answer (score 1):

That integral is kind of problematic. If $\sec^{-1}x$ means "inverse secant of $x$", then $[0,1)$ is outside the domain. If $\cot^{-1}x$ means "reciprocal of cotangent of $x$, then the integral will diverge near $\frac{\pi}2$ for example.